# Combining regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, expression

I'd like to combine the regular expressions `\w+` and `[a-z]` together in Python to only accept a word that is all lowercase, but cannot seem to figure out the right way to do that.  Does anyone know how?

Comment: `\w` is a shortcut for `[a-zA-Z_]`, so it already contains `[a-z]`. Also, as a general rule you should try to format your question to make what you want to do (match a lowercase word) appear more clearly, then explaining where you're stuck: your question will be susceptible to help more people stuggling on the same obstacle. And if you give more details, are more specific, people won't have to shoot random code snippets in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want lowercase words, all you need is `[a-z]+`

`\w` includes uppercase letters, digits, and underscore

Comment: I figured out something similar to this, but you're answer definitely helped.                                                                  Thank you!                                                             -S

Answer (score 2):

Try the regex as following

`\b[a-z]+\b`

[image]

Live [Demo](http://www.regexper.com/#/%5Cb%5Ba-z%5D+%5Cb/)

Comment: what did you use for that graphic? please tell me it autogenerated from the regex, cause that would be awesome!

Comment: @JoranBeasley FRom regexper

Comment: @RakeshKR - In Python, you do not need to enclose Regex patterns in forwardslashes.  Your pattern should be `\b[a-z]+\b`, unless you specifically want to capture the `/`'s on each end.

Comment: @iCodez ThanKz For Your Valuable Info.

Answer (score 0):

To find all lowercase words you should use the regular expression as shown in the below example:

```
re.findall('\b[a-z]+\b', my_string)
```

You don't need to worry about combining the `\w` in order to find all lowercase words. The regular expression used will just find strings that only contain lowercase letters.

Comment: However the OP wanted to find words. Your example would show 'AabcBdefC' returning ['abc', 'def'] when it should return that it is not a word containing all lower case letters.

Comment: @sabbahillel Damn, you're right, editing. If you look at the edit history you will see that I had a working solution originally but tried to simplify.

Comment: That is often why I often expand the suggested answer such as putting it in a loop rather than trying for a single line list comprehension. Murphy keeps getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a word string and want to verify that it is lower case, than you would use the str.islower() function. If you have a string of words separated by spaces, the you can use

```
  lst = words.split(' ')
  for word in lst:
    print word, 'lower case test is', word.islower()
```

Note that I did not use list comprehension in order to break up the individual parts.

Answer (score 0):

Since \w+ is the same as:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]+
```

I think you're looking for this:

```
[a-z_]+
```

Or perhaps

```
[a-z0-9_]+
```

Answer (score -1):

So I was actually able to get it to work like this : `[a-z]\w+`.